# how to obtain in node style definition size of `shadow xshift`?

Tags: tikz-pgf

drop shadows use transform canvas, consequently node's shadow is not inside picture bounding box. if i like to draw a node from left to right border of the tex area such, that shadow not spill out of text border, i need to reduce node width for amount of `shadow xshift` size. I wonder, how to obtain its size in definition of node style.

so far i try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                shadows}

%------------- show page layout. don't use this in real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \vspace*{5ex}
    \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
DS/.style args = {#1/#2}{drop shadow={fill=orange,
                                     shadow xshift=#1,
                                     shadow yshift=#2}
                        },
      A/.style = {draw, fill=yellow!30, % my node
                  text width=\linewidth-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}% this work
                                       -  \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/shadow xshift},% this doesn't provide shadow xshift size
                  align=center,
                },
                                ]
\node (a) [DS=12pt/-4pt, inner sep=12 pt, A] {my annotated text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

as you can see, my attempt was unsuccessful. the question is, where is the error in using of the `\pgfkeysvalueof{...}`. did i at use of `\pgfkeysvalueof{...}` miss something or is my attempt to determine the size of the `shadow xshift` incorrect?

or is my expectation, that on this way is possible to obtain size of `shadow xshift` naive?

Comment: Why do you want to cast a shadow? Are you a groundhog?

Comment: @marmot, good question :-)  i had some (crazy) ideas about composing shapes styles from predefined building blocks. another reason was to learn a bit more about `tikz`. and not on the end, i'm not groundhog :-).

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround you could perhaps use `.store in` to save `#2` in the `DS` style to a macro, and subsequently use that macro in `A`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                shadows}

%------------- show page layout. don't use this in real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \vspace*{5ex}
    \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
      DS/.style args = {#1/#2}{drop shadow={fill=orange,
                                     shadow xshift=#1,
                                     shadow yshift=#2},
                               shadowshift/.store in=\SXShift,
                               shadowshift=#1
                        },
      A/.style = {draw, fill=yellow!30, % my node
                  text width=\linewidth-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}% this work
                                       -  \SXShift,
                  align=center,
                },
                                ]
\node (a) [DS=12pt/-4pt, inner sep=12 pt, A] {my annotated text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for answer (+1). since i'm not familiar with `.store in` i will first search/read in `tikz` manual to find more information. on the first sight it seem to be very promising.